# Calling embedded systems vs. calling embedded electronics

Tags: embedded, terminology, system

I know that the name "Embedded systems" is way more adopted worldwide. However, it always intrigues me since, in engineering, the term "system" is usually used when it is intended to generalize the application area.

For instance, the expression "system" seems to fit well in the field of "system identification". What is "system"? Well, it can be a ton of systems: Biological system, Mechanical system, Pneumatic system, Electrical system, etc...

But for "Embedded system", what is "system"? It is clearly nongeneric. Even though there are a lot of elements that comprise the solution, it is always the electronic device (the hardware) that is embedded into.

I keep referring this field of knowledge as embedded systems just because it is already named like that, but I've never hear a reasonable explanation for it...

Comment: An embedded system always does something so it has software inputs (sensors) and outputs (actuators). It's not just printed circuit boards.

Comment: Embedded COMPUTER system?

Comment: @DKNguyen I didn't say that it is just printed circuit boards, but it is actually the electronic device that is embedded into, not something else.

Comment: @Bryan  computer system it is used rarely as well. Even though, wouldn't be embedded computer enough? what is the necessity of "system"?

Comment: The engineering doesn’t necessarily stop at the boundary of the electronics. Eg a car Injection system consists of electronics, electrical, electromechanical and mechanical items. The electronics and firmware need to accomodate the environment. The concept of ‘systems engineering’ is also part of the skill set.

Comment: Names just pop up from hearsay when a lot of people talk about vague and broad topics. It's nothing to brood over. As a rule of thumb, the lesser people know about a certain buzzword technology, the stranger will the emerging term become as it is forming from their hubbub. "Information Technology", "Machine learning", "Internet of things", "Agile methodology". Less embarrassing things to say than "Dude, I have absolutely no clue what I'm talking about".

Answer (score 1):

> But for "Embedded system", what is "system"? It is clearly nongeneric.

Remember "Signals and Systems" from the university. System is defined as a block (or black box?) which has at least one input to generate at least one output.

If something having an embedded logic element (MCU, MPU, FPGA, PLC, or anything that you embed a software in) has at least one input and generates at least one output (using the inputs of course or else we can't define the transfer function) then it's called "embedded system" regardless of the types of the inputs and outputs.

In other words, if the system requires an embedded software to run a specific function or to do a specific job (i.e. to generate at least one output using at least one input) then it's called embedded system.

> it is always the electronic device (the hardware) that is embedded into

I have always found this definition wrong. Because an embedded system doesn't have to be pure electronic e.g. a PCB having at least one embedded logic controller on it and some connectors. Obviously it can contain different sub-systems.

Imagine an equipment that generates different sounds depending on water flow, and it has a software running on it. I can call the entire system "embedded system". However, there's a water flow sensor and a power amplifier inside the equipment, so the circuit that gets its input from the sensor and generates signal for the PA can still be called "embedded system" as well. Because it still gets at least one input and has at least one output.